# Is Flash Remoting Services dead?

Tags: flash, remoting

I have a potential client that build something with Flash Remoting Services.  It looks there was some sort of server product offered back in 2002-2003, but I've been unable to see if it did anything so complex that it could not be replaced with a simple webservice.  Does any one know what happened to this product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm too late to answer this but, I have some experience with Flash Remoting with asp.net using flash remoting component and other frameworks, I also tried all those frameworks with flex as well, source code is also available for download, so just go ahead and use it for free

I got many questions from that blog entry via email about source code setup and other implementations, so that explains there are lots of developers who actually atleast try this

[Here](http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2009/03/flash-remoting-with-aspnet.html) is a link of my [blog post](http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2009/03/flash-remoting-with-aspnet.html)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can find support information at Adobe's [Flash Remoting Support](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash_remoting/) site.  So, it is not so wholly dead that if you already have a licence for it, you cannot get support.  That said, I've no idea how much it is really used these days, so I can't really answer your main question.

Comment: i did see that by doing a Google Search... but the real question is should we try to find someone who knows something about the product or is that just a wild goose chase?